# Options for PCI-DSS 11.5 - Deploy file integrity monitoring software

Tags: monitoring, pci-dss

I'm looking for options to be compliant with PCI-DSS section 11.5 for some servers I manage at the datacenter. There are several servers (less than 20) and they are mostly CentOS5, but there are some RHEL4 and Solaris9 Sparc. I believe [Tripwire, Inc.](http://www.tripwire.com/) is the leader in this area, but I am looking for additional options, both commercial and FOSS. Please include your experience reasons for using the software you recommend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at [Samhain](http://la-samhna.de/samhain/) for an Open Source solution.

When I used it in my last job, it was only a file integrity checking solution, but it seems it has since evolved in a more complete solution...

Comment: Any comments on using it? Easy to use? Difficult to install? etc.

Answer (score 2):

As a commercial option (i.e. typically better supported and easier to use, but obviously more expensive :), I'd suggest [Verisys](http://www.ionx.co.uk), a commercial file integrity monitoring system.

My main reason for suggesting it is that it's a lot cheaper than Tripwire. It doesn't provide all the 'change management' kind of features that Tripwire does, but not everyone needs that. Verisys is a lot easier to use too.

Answer (score 1):

Additional options:

http://www.la-samhna.de/library/scanners.html

Make your own educated choice. Depending on the number of hosts you have, having a centralized reporting server or mechanism is going to be important. Take that into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

[OSSEC](http://www.ossec.net/) will also do integrity monitoring and is dead simple to use. It integrates very well with SIEMs such as Prelude if you are using that. Has a web interface available that will make checking the integrity information really easy.